# How to remove the share/later/like/embed options from the vimeo video player?

Tags: objective-c, vimeo, video-player

I am using this code for playing vimeo videos but I want to remove the share/later/like/embed options from its player.

```
embedHTML = @"<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color:black; color:black; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><iframe src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/%@\" width=\"600.0strong text\" height=\"300.0\" frameborder=\"0\"></body></html>";
```

Please tell me how to remove these options from the vimeo video player?

Answer (score 2):

Ive tried doing this myself. After a conversation with the Vimeo developers it seems it cannot be done.

https://vimeo.com/forums/feature_requests/topic:75400